# How to make a scrollable submenu or go to that section if you are in a different page with laravel & angular

Tags: php, html, angularjs, vue.js

I am wondering if the following can be done:

1. Have a navbar that looks like this: [image]

and have it scroll to any of the sections on the dropdown menu (i.e. Testimonials) and if you are in a different page like Contact, then go to the About page and scroll to Testimonials.

2. Can this be done with Vue or Angular?
3. Is this a bad practice? Should I just remove the submenu and let users scroll down the About section to learn about the services? I only have two services, and it seems rather superfluous to have an additional page to display them.

Comment: I am not sure about Angular but [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) has scroll functionality built in. In either case this can be solved with [vanilla js](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/).

Comment: I thought Vue router was meant for SPA (?) "Creating a Single-page Application with Vue + Vue Router is dead simple."

Comment: Yes, it typically is but I do not know the scope of your project so figured it might be noteworthy.

Comment: It is a very simple website to test my abilities. I only want to use a simple database to store my recipes and articles. I wanted  my website to be a MPA since I have used Vue router for SPA.

Comment: Well if your nav/subnav isn't going to be built with Vue or Angular you can use vanilla javascript as mentioned in a previous comment of mine. AFAIK there's no issue with directing users to relevant content but I am sure there's UX/UI articles are there that support and contradict my statement.